# How to reference output variable from azure pipeline job that uses matrix strategy?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the following azure pipeline yml (at the bottom, some parts omitted). I have 3 jobs in total. The first runs with a matrix strategy, the second runs normally and the third attempts to pick up output variables set by the previous two jobs.

The output variable reference for the second job seems to work fine. But when referencing the output variables rom the first job, I don't know what job name to use.The job is called 'Build' but the name seems to be influenced by the names in the strategy matrix. When I run:

```
echo $(Agent.JobName)
echo $(System.JobName)
echo $(System.JobDisplayName)
```

For a job called 'Build' with a matrix entry called 'linux' then I get:

```
Build linux
linux
Build linux
```

But using any of the following don't seem to work:

```
$[ dependencies.Build.outputs['SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]
$[ dependencies.linux.outputs['SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]
$[ dependencies.Build_linux.outputs['SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]
$[ dependencies['Build linux'].outputs['SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]
```

How is this meant to work? The fact that the reference to the second job works gives me hope but I'm clearly getting something wrong with the job name. I've tried so many combinations now that I've completely lost track of what I have and haven't tried.

When the results are reported, I see a value for the `create_universal_macos_binary` job status but not for the others which come from the first job.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    timeoutInMinutes: 90
    strategy:
      matrix:
          linux:
            tripletCompressed: 'x64linux'
          win64:
            tripletCompressed: 'x64windows'
          macOS_x64:
            tripletCompressed: 'x64osx'
          macOS_arm64:
            tripletCompressed: 'arm64osx'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(imageName)
    steps:

    ...

    # Set output variable with job status
    - bash: |
        echo $(Agent.JobName)
        echo $(System.JobName)
        echo $(System.JobDisplayName)
        echo "vso[task.setvariable variable=$(tripletCompressed)Status;isOutput=true]${AGENT_JOBSTATUS}"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$(tripletCompressed)Status;isOutput=true]${AGENT_JOBSTATUS}"
      name: SetJobStatus
      displayName: Set Job Status Variable

  - job: create_universal_macos_binary
    displayName: 'Create universal MacOS binary'
    dependsOn: 'Build'
    condition: and(and(eq(${{ parameters.BUILD_MACOS_X64 }}, true), eq(${{ parameters.BUILD_MACOS_ARM64 }}, true)), ${{ containsValue(parameters.TARGET_PACKAGES, 'core') }})
    pool:
      vmImage: macOS-11

    ...

    # Set output variable with job status
    - bash: |
        echo $(Agent.JobName)
        echo $(System.JobName)
        echo $(System.JobDisplayName)
        echo "vso[task.setvariable variable=universalStatus;isOutput=true]${AGENT_JOBSTATUS}"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=universalStatus;isOutput=true]${AGENT_JOBSTATUS}"
      name: SetJobStatus
      displayName: Set Job Status Variable

  - job: message_teams
    displayName: 'Report Status to Teams'
    dependsOn:
      - 'Build'
      - create_universal_macos_binary
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

    variables:
      windowsStatus: $[ dependencies.win64.outputs['SetJobStatus.x64windowsStatus'] ]
      linuxStatus: $[ dependencies['Build linux'].outputs['SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]
      macosIntelStatus: $[ dependencies.macOS_x64.outputs['SetJobStatus.x64osxStatus'] ]
      macosArmStatus: $[ dependencies.macOS_arm64.outputs['SetJobStatus.arm64osxStatus'] ]
      universalStatus: $[ dependencies.create_universal_macos_binary.outputs['SetJobStatus.universalStatus'] ]

    steps:

    ...

    - task: PythonScript@0
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'filePath'
        scriptPath: ./process-status.py
      env:
        CI_BUILD_ID: $(Build.BuildId)
        WINDOWS_STATUS: $(windowsStatus)
        LINUX_STATUS: $(linuxStatus)
        MACOS_INTEL_STATUS: $(macosIntelStatus)
        MACOS_ARM_STATUS: $(macosArmStatus)
        UNIVERSAL_STATUS: $(universalStatus)
      condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), ${{ parameters.REPORT_TO_TEAMS }})
      displayName: "Report result to Teams"
```

Comment: I've raised a question on GitHub via the azure docs feedback link and will report back if I get any information there: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/12904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) for details.

[image]

To get the output variable in the next job in the same stage, you could use format : $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['linux.SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]

In your issue, if you set variables in job 3 message_team as belows, you are supposed to use them.

```
variables:
  windowsStatus: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['win64.SetJobStatus.x64windowsStatus'] ]
  linuxStatus: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['linux.SetJobStatus.x64linuxStatus'] ]
  macosIntelStatus: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['macOS_x64.SetJobStatus.x64osxStatus'] ]
  macosArmStatus: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['macOS_arm64.SetJobStatus.arm64osxStatus'] ]
  universalStatus: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['SetJobStatus.universalStatus'] ]
```

If you echo the variables here like this:

```
steps:
- bash: |
    echo $(windowsStatus)
    echo $(linuxStatus)
    echo $(macosIntelStatus)
    echo $(macosArmStatus)
    echo $(universalStatus)
```

You will able to get the output like this:

[image]

I hope this could do some help.

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to be working. I can see that it is clearly documented. I've clearly failed to see it. I'm not sure why. I did spend quite some time double checking my work against https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job and assumed that it would be documented there if anywhere but I'm glad to see it is on the page with a complete example.

Comment: Hi @MichaelJones, please proceed to try whether it works on your side. If it helps, just a remind of [ accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks again for your warm reply.  :-)